# \appendix command adds a period after section number before it was called

Tags: sectioning, numbering, koma-script, appendices

I am using the [scrartcl class](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrartcl). To make an appendix with tables and figures I am using the command `\appendix`. After it, I simply continue using `\section` to make sections.

I noticed that if I use `\appendix`, then a period is added after the number of the section, say "*A.1. Sample section*", which is good according to the Koma Script manual. On the other hand, this dot is added also to the **preceding** sections, i.e. those before `\appendix` was called. Indeed I get something like "*1. Introduction*" which I don't want.

For the sake of clarity, there is no dot after the section number if `\appendix` is not at all called.

Answer (score 3):

There is an KOMA-Script option `numbers`. Default is `numbers=auto`. That means there will be no period at the end of the numbers if only arabic numbers are used. But if there are roman numbers or letters in the numbering scheme there will be a dot at the end of *every* number.

If you decide there should be no period at the end of the numbers use

```
numbers=noendperiod
```

Note that this option can be set only in the preamble for the whole document.

```
\documentclass[
  numbers=noendperiod
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\appendix
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

If you really want the period only after the section numbers in the appendix you have to redefine `\sectionformat`, `\sectionmarkformat` and `\addsectiontocentry` at the beginning of the appendix:

```
\documentclass[
   numbers=noendperiod
]{scrartcl}%

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto{\appendix}{%
  \renewcommand\sectionformat{\thesection.\enskip}%
  \renewcommand\sectionmarkformat{\thesection.\enskip}%
  \renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{%
     \ifstr{#1}{}{%
       \addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{#2}%
     }{%
       \addtocentrydefault{section}{\protect\def\protect\autodot{.}#1}{#2}%
     }%
  }%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\appendix
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi esdd, many thanks! What about having the dot still after the letter, for instance _A. Appendix_, but not in the rest of the document?

Comment: @Pietro It is possible but unusual - see the Image with the table of contents in my edited answer.